# JS Create delay on Select Drop-Down Menu Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, delay

I have a drop-down menu that lists subjects. I am loading those subjects via an AJAX call. The subjects load properly, they just don't load fast enough to populate the select menu until AFTER the menu has been opened. This causes the user to need to open the menu, close the menu, then open it again.

How can I cause a delay on the drop-down-menu open to give the response enough time to populate the drop-down menu? Thanks for any and all help.

---

**Code:**

**Drop-down Menu**

```
<div id="subjectForm" class="form-row">
    <label>1) Subject Selection:</label>
    <select name="subject" id="subjectSelect" class="input-medium">
        <option value="0">All</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**AJAX Call**

```
document.getElementById("subjectForm").addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    var selectCount = $('#subjectSelect option').size();

    if(selectCount == 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/v2/subjects?',    
            method: 'GET',
            data: {'core': number},
            success: function (data) {
                // Populates the $subjectSelect filter with subjects
                // For each grade brought back from response, add it to the grade filter
                $.each(data, function(i, subject){
                    $('#subjectSelect')
                        .append($('<option></option>')
                        .attr("value", subject.id)
                        .text(subject.title));
                });// each
            }// success
        });// ajax
    }// end if
}, false);// #subjectForm clicked
```

Comment: is the dropdown menu a `<select>` element?

Comment: render elements to selectbox after a timeout, use setTimeout()

Comment: [What does your code look like](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @whipdancer sorry about that, I just added my code.

Comment: What is `number` --> `data: {'core': number}`?  Is that defaulted or is the user selecting something, then clicking the select list?

Comment: @whipdancer that is defaulted in the response. It is a place-holder for a future select menu. Currently the subject select is the first menu the user will select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `number` value is defaulted, I would change the load to happen on document ready, rather than waiting until the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loadSubjectSelect = function(){
        var selectCount = $('#subjectSelect option').size();
        if(selectCount == 1) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/v2/subjects?',    
                method: 'GET',
                data: {'core': number},
                success: function (data) {
                    // Populates the $subjectSelect filter with subjects
                    // For each grade brought back from response, add it to the grade filter
                    $.each(data, function(i, subject){
                        $('#subjectSelect')
                            .append($('<option></option>')
                            .attr("value", subject.id)
                            .text(subject.title));
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };

    loadSubjectSelect();    
})();
```

Then when you add the other menu, you can call `loadSubjectSelect()` on its click event.

Comment: Perfect, much simpler than what I was trying. This should work well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Render options after some seconds

```
success: function (data) {
    // Populates the $subjectSelect filter with subjects
    // For each grade brought back from response, add it to the grade filter
    var myoptions = "";
    $.each(data, function(i, subject){
        myoptions += "<option value='"+subject.id+"'>"+subject.title+"</option>";      
    });
    $('#subjectSelect').html(myoptions);
}
```

Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Is this defined in the success of the response? If you look at the code I added I am appending `<option>` elements onto the select in the success. My issue is that the drop-down loads before AJAX even returns with a success.